# Grub crashing on startup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I know this sounds like many other posts on this site, but it is, as far as I'm concerned, quite different.

I recently tried to install Ubuntu LTS in dual-Boot with parrot os.

The problem is, that every time I try to boot using the bootloader installed by Ubuntu, my laptop turns on (by that I mean the power indicator lights up), shows the factory boot splash (my laptop is from Acer, wich is why it displays the Acer logo), shows the little grey "GRUB" text in the top left, and then restarts for no reason, creating an infinite loop that can only be stopped by cutting the power or going into the EFI Setup.
I have no idea as for why this is happening.

However the Parrot OS bootloader works perfectly fine.

Edit:
I managed to fix the issue by selecting the grubx64.efi in the EFI/ubuntu folder within Ubuntu's bootloader partition. For some reason the file BOOTX64 in EFI/BOOT doesn't work or smth idk maybe it was the wrong file to begin with.

Comment: Best to remove all the off-topic Zorin stuff and focus on what you did with Ubuntu LTS before this gets closed.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Zorin forum.  (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Zorin so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux* found in the on-topic link)